# SU retag request: hdd, bluescreen, karmic, torrent, ...

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Tags in need of automated retagging:

- <strike>[**[xp]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/xp) (31) to [**[windows-xp]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-xp) (1987)</strike>
- <strike>[**[vista]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vista) (57) to [**[windows-vista]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-vista) (1239)</strike>
- <strike>[**[hdd]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hdd) (37) to [**[hard-drive]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive) (493)</strike>
- [**[bluescreen]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bluescreen) (33) to [**[bsod]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bsod) (65) **[*]**
- [**[karmic]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/karmic) (47) to [**[ubuntu-9.10]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-9.10) (268)
- <strike>[**[torrent]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/torrent) (24) to [**[bittorrent]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bittorrent) (60)</strike>
- <strike>[**[font]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/font) (26) to [**[fonts]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/fonts) (117)</strike>

This is part of regular tag maintenance, and we can probably expect most of these tags back eventually.  Tag counts are reasonably current as of right now.

**[*]:** I don't prefer one over the other.  Tho as balpha [points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42283/su-retag-request-hdd-bluescreen-karmic-torrent/42290#42290), *[bsod]* may be the clearer of the two.

**Updated:** added **[font]** to the list.

---

With regards to the **[xp]** and **[vista]** tags, it's common that these tags are accompanied by the **[windows]** tag.

- If the **[windows]** tag *preceeds* and *adjoins* the **[xp]** or **[vista]** tag, I assume the proper tagging should be to merge the two tags, not to replace the second tag.
- I assume the automatic retag just replaces tags and has little capability to handle special requests like the above restriction.
- For example:
  Original tags: **[foo] [windows] [xp] [bar]**
  Automatic retag: **[foo] [windows] [windows-xp] [bar]**
  Proper retag: **[foo] [windows-xp] [bar]**

With this in mind, I've retagged **[windows]+[xp]** and **[windows]+[vista]** questions manually, only when they met the requirement in the first bullet point above.  However, if my assumptions are improper, please let me know so I can refrain in the future.

Comment: I would like to hear if anyone does not agree with these re-tags. Anyone have issues or opinions on any of these?

Comment: @Troggy: thx, me too.  i take it you don't have any specific issues with them (or if you do you'll let me know shortly... :)

Comment: Excellent! Go for it.

Comment: Why aren't these retagged already?!? :P

Comment: When I do retagging, I'll do queries for combinations of the individual words (such as "[windows] AND [xp]") and retag those questions manually. Usually there aren't very many. I'd help out, but I don't have enough rep to retag on SU.

Comment: @jon seigel: i do the same thing, usually just by editing the URL instead of using the search UI, eg: http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows+xp

Comment: @~quack: Yeah, there was a feature request to keep the search text in the box when only tags get entered, but it hasn't gone through yet. Also, the 3 remaining questions with [windows] AND [xp] need retagging. Generally I don't rely on the order of tags (i.e., [xp]+[windows] = [windows]+[xp], but obviously look at the question context to make sure the correct information is captured).

Comment: @jon: one's migrated, which means locked, which means a diamond mod gets to do it.  the others didn't fit the criteria i used; i specifically used tag order as an indication that the user might have chosen the combined tag instead of the individual tags.  not a big deal either way.  unless someone else gets them manually, i'll let the batch retagging pick them up.

Comment: @~quack: 111123 needs [windows-7] (read question body), 82208 [xp]+[windows] --> [windows-xp], and 77017 flag for moderator attention (copy/paste help for you: "Please retag [windows]+[xp] to [windows-xp]. Thanks.").

Comment: @jon: oy.  fine, done.  except the flag: seriously, the batch convert will pick it up.

Comment: @~quack: Thanks ;) As for flagging, when I've been going through my requests, at least Bill the Lizard seems content to help me organize things. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41365/tag-merge-request-os-x-related-tags-on-so I'm curious to know more about how the batch process works.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with most of them. However, it needs to be checked if [bluescreen] really always refers to a BSOD. It might as well be someone asking for a program to do video matting (bluescreen/greenscreen, you know).

Comment: this is a fair concern, but all the current **[bluescreen]** questions appear to be eligible for the **[bsod]** tag as well (ie, none of them are about video matting/greenscreen tech).  i just did a cursory check; if anyone else wants to look: http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bluescreen

Comment: ...though the potential ambiguity you bring up suggests that **[bsod]** is a better tag choice for the "windows crashes" phenomenon.  :)

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with changing karmic to ubuntu-9.10.

I think it should be the other way around. Most beginners don't memorize version numbers but if you say 'karmic' they think 'Ah! I have that.'

Comment: all the other ubuntu versions are represented by their versions... [ubuntu-8.04-lts], [ubuntu-8.10], [ubuntu-9.04], [ubuntu-9.10], etc.  if you're not familiar with ubuntu, the codename tags won't make any sense at all.  then there's a further problem of possible conflicts -- we could mitigate by using the full codename, but honestly, who remembers it's *[karmic-koala]*, not just *[karmic]*?

Comment: Good point. Then again... who can forget the full codename? I never have trouble remembering them thanks to the alliteration.

Comment: the main reason i'd prefer version numbers is that you can find them all with this style url: http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu~ ... i think newbies will *recognize* the version even if they *remember* the codename.  if we change one to the codename, we'll need to do that for all -- which is doable, but it's a broader discussion than *this* question is setup for.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finished off the xp ones I saw.  I also performed the [windows-vista] and [bittorrent] merges also as I thought those were good ones to do. The [fonts] and [hard-drive] retag's are complete.

You are correct ~quack in that the merge operations simply select a master tag and a tag to remove.  The removed tag is then replaced with the master tag and does not handle special cases.  With the vista tagged questions, I will just remove the [windows] tag where it is not needed as I go through questions.  The generic [windows] needs to stay in place though as some questions simply deal with windows in general terms.  This is where we can use anyone with the appropriate reputation to re-tag questions to properly categorize questions.

I would like to hear more input on the ubuntu and bsod tags.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10941/blue-screen-of-death-dupe-derp-at-super-user

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42493/retag-request-xp-windows-xp-on-super-user

Comment: thanks.  i'm intending to open a separate discussion thread regarding the conventions used when tagging the various MS Office products.  i think the ubuntu tags ought to get their own discussion as well.  i'd prefer that we went ahead and merged *[karmic]* into *[ubuntu-9.10]* now, since that's the current convention -- they can be changed again later if the community decides to change the convention.